# Fetch documents from firestore and add fields to it

Tags: android, ios, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to fetch all the documents in a firestore collection and add fields in those documents in flutter but I'm not sure how to go about it. I tried this but it didn't seem to do anything.

```
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: courseRef.snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot){
        if (!snapshot.hasData){
          return circularProgress();
        }
        snapshot.data.forEach((doc){
          courseRef.document(doc).updateData({
            'id' : doc.id,
            'isTutor': '',
            'isStudent': '',
          });
        });
      });
  }
```

Comment: I have no idea why this was downvoted when I need assistance.

Comment: `snapshot.data.forEach((doc)` here doc is of type `DocumentSnapshot` you cannot assign it in `courseRef.document(doc)` as it takes a string .Instead you should use `courseRef.document(doc.documentId)`

Comment: Good catch @ShubhamGupta. Do you want to write it up as an answer, so that Priscilla can accept it and others can upvote it?

Comment: @ShubhamGupta you should

Comment: I have posted it as an answer and I would strongly recommend you define the type that will save you from such errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

snapshot.data.forEach((doc) here doc is of type DocumentSnapshot you cannot assign it in courseRef.document(doc) as it takes a string .Instead you should use courseRef.document(doc.documentId)

Here is the updated code.

```
return StreamBuilder(
  stream: courseRef.snapshots(),
  builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot){
    if (!snapshot.hasData){
      return circularProgress();
    }
    snapshot.data.forEach((DocumentSnapshot doc){
      courseRef.document(doc.documentId).updateData({
        'id' : doc.id,
        'isTutor': '',
        'isStudent': '',
      });
    });
  });
}
```